# Pass an array element (struct) to function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct as below

```
typedef struct _someStruct
{
int V1;
char    V2[10];
} SomeStruct;

SomeStruct *struct;
int elemNo = FillStruct(&struct);
for (i=0; i<elemNo; i++)
    PrintElem(&struct[i]);
```

Function PrintElem is as below:

```
void PrintElem(SomeStruct *s)
{
    printf("\n\tV1   : %d\n\tV2   : %s\n", s->V1, s->V2);
}
```

Code fails in the loop from 2'n or 3'rd element.

Any suggestion on what's wrong?

**EDIT:**
Actually the PrintElem was (the reasoin I made it this way is the fact that the real struct had about 30 fields with long names, so I made it to make the code readable) :

```
void PrintElem(SomeStruct *s)
{
    printf(
        "\n\tV1   : %d"
        "\n\tV2   : %s\n",
        s->V1, s->V2);
}
```

I didn't thought this can make a difference, but it did (actually WAS the key of the problem - see my own answer below)
I just post it hoping it will help someone later.

Thanks all for all suggestions and for your time

Comment: You expect us to believe `SomeStruct *struct;` compiles ? Post the real code. Are you using both C and C++ ? Pick one.

Comment: Can you post what FillStruct does?

Comment: That can't be your real code. You have `v2` instead of `V2`, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `FillStruct()` function.

Comment: It's obviously pseudo-code people, try to be less critical.

Comment: When he's asking for specific help, posting anything less than specific code is sort of counterproductive. I think being critical is legit here.

Comment: @James McLaughlin - thanks for your edit

Comment: @Chris Farmer, the code was very specific. However the real code was much more longer, and simplifiying it was just a way to prove respect for other's time, by not forcing them to read 100 lines of unrelevant code. The real struct had about 30 fields, with very long names, and defines in string field size.

Comment: @cnicutar, yes, I expect you should believe that, if you use C/C++. And I don't see where's the mix of C/C++ that bother you that much? And is any problem mixing in VS 2010? I don't think so

Comment: @bzamfir Thing is `SomeStruct *struct;` doesn't compile in either of those languages because **`struct` is a keyword**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form of PrintElem should be

```
void PrintElem(SomeStruct *s)
{
printf(
    "\n\tV1   : %d"\
    "\n\tV2   : %s\n",
    s->V1, s->V2);
}
```

Thank you all for help

Answer (score 2):

This one got a few issues, but let's try to sort them out

```
    typedef struct _someStruct
    {
    int V1;
    char    V2[10];
    } SomeStruct;

    /* assuming you create an array of pointers to structures allocated from heap
       and then return the data to the struct1 double pointer */
    SomeStruct ** struct1;
    int elemNo = FillStruct(struct1);
    for (i=0; i<elemNo; i++)
        PrintElem(struct[i]);

    void PrintElem(SomeStruct *s)
    {
        printf("\n\tV1   : %d\n\tV2   : %s\n", s->V1, s->v2);
    }
```

Hope this helps, if you could clarify FillStruct, that would help.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this approach, but got the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In fact SomeStruct is the name of the variable not the type. I would suggest you split the typedef and variable definition on two lines:

```
struct _someStruct
{
  int V1;
  char    V2[10];
};

_someStruct *struct;
int elemNo = FillStruct(&struct);
for (i=0; i<elemNo; i++)
  PrintElem(&struct[i]);


void PrintElem(_someStruct *s)
{
   printf("\n\tV1   : %d\n\tV2   : %s\n", s->V1, s->v2);
}
```

Also make sure that in FillStruct you allocate an array of type _someStruct, not just one element. Otherwise this will not be strange at all.

Answer (score 1):

From these lines:

```
SomeStruct *struct;
int elemNo = FillStruct(&struct);
```

I assume you want `FillStruct` function also to allocate memory for these structs. Your problem is most likely in the body of this function (you are allocating too small memory block or you return incorrect value).

`FillStruct` function could look like this:

```
int FillStruct(SomeStruct **s)
{
    *s = malloc( sizeof(SomeStruct) * 10 );
    // fill members of these structs
    return 10;
}
```

Also note that `struct` is a keyword, you can't use it as a name of variable.

Comment: Yes, FillStruct does what you say, but it was ok. The issue with with the format string in printf